# Force delay on apache response times

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

Is there a way to make an Apache response time to take at least 10 seconds?
It's fine if it takes more than 10 seconds but I would like the fastest response times to take at least 10 seconds.

Comment: You want all existing responses to take 10 second, or you just want at least one URL that takes that long? If the latter, write a quick CGI script with a 10 second sleep/pause.

Comment: You might be able to achieve that with the [iptables QUEUE](http://people.redhat.com/berrange/notes/network-delay.html) target and some userspace programming or a WAN simulator.

Comment: Causing Apache itself to sleep for 10 seconds might open up nice possibilities for DoS. They just have to hit reload n times and your queue is full for the next 10 seconds.

Comment: @sami kuhmonen, But apache can process several concurrent requests, right?

Comment: @HélioSantos Yes, but only as many as the configuration states. If you have 100 concurrent requests, the evil user just has to send 100 requests and then Apache won't answer to anyone for 10 seconds. And of course the limit could be set to 1000000, but even that amount of requests could be sent and also that amount of connections could cause other problems.

Comment: @sami kuhmonen, is not for a production environment, I just need to run some tests. I explain it better here http://serverfault.com/questions/595422/force-delay-on-apache-reverse-proxy-response-times

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with mod_lua in Apache v2.4 and possibly mod_python/mod_perl with Apache v2.2 or v2.4.

You register a handler than simply waits 10 seconds and then returns `apache2.DECLINED` to indicate it will not handle the request, which should then process normally.

There is an example handler in the mod_lua documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_lua.html